I can't seem to make a grid fill in 4.2
Im kind of a newbie to blender. This is a new cylinder and when I try to make a grid fill
an error comes out.

I'm not sure how to see if the loops are connected or not, this kind of problem did not happen in 3.6, when it changed to 4.2 this error apeared.

here is the error list

You can typically grid fill holes in meshes, I see an ngon face already there

You can't Grid Fill when there's already a face there! Delete the top face, select the edge loop and try again. - That's the same in 3.6 by the way. - You get a brief error message on the bottom toolbar in both versions.

youre right! thank you very much!!!!!!!!

@JohnEason that appears to be an answer. Please post it as such, so the question will be marked as answered.
